# Check, that set of objects can be ordered (transitivity)

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a set of objects (e.g. strings)  `{"AB", "BA", "ABA", "AABA", ...}`

I have a function, that can compare two objects: `func fn(a, b string) bool` (`true`, if `a>b`). `fn(a, b) == !fn(b, a)`

How can I check, that I can unambiguously order the initial set? That `fn` is transitive over the given set.

E.g., if `fn(a, b) == true`, `fn(b, c) == true`, but `fn(a, c) == false`, then `fn` is not transitive and it can't order the given set.

I was thinking about sorting the set, with `fn` as compare function,  then compare each pair of elements again. But I can't "prove" myself, that it's a working solution.

Comment: You can check all possible triples. That is sufficient. a>b & b>c =>  a>c

Comment: There does not need to be an defined order, because >= is also transitive and how would you sort elements that are equal in a consistent way?

Comment: look up "toposort".

Comment: This question is equivalent to "How to detect a cycle in a directed graph?"